# Mongodb 3D geometry - query by distance

Tags: mongodb, 3d

I have a collection of (X,Y,Z) points in Mongo database - is there any way to precisely query for points within given distance of some coordinate? For example, within 50 units of 0,0,0.

The most prevalent answer seems to be to strip the least significant coordinate and use 2D $near query, but this approach would lead to unacceptable loss of precision with my data set.

Are there any plugins available for 3D queries? Or some clever query tricks? Failing that, could you suggest some external service like elasticsearch that works well with 3D geometry?

If it changes anything, I'm dealing with ~10 pre-set distances, couple thousand points that change relatively rarely, always querying for points within a distance from another point, and reaching maximum ~20% of other points from any given one at the biggest distance. So pre-computing is an option, but I'd like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: looks like you are searching closests stars :)

Comment: I have sometimes calculated the distance between points using the modulus which formula for 3d is:

(x1,y1,z1) to (x2,y2,z2)

sqrt( (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 + (z2-z1)^2)

But I am not sure how you can apply it on mongodb,

Comment: MongoDB's geometry functions are built for 2d geometry, either flat or on a sphere. There's currently (2.6) no support for 3d geometry of any sort.